# MTD Function not working with SCOPE

Tags: ssas, mdx

```
SCOPE ([Measures].[Net IMS Volume]);
 ( [Time].[Time Calculations].[MTD] ) 
   = SUM(
       MTD([Time].[Time Hierarchy 1].CURRENTMEMBER)
     ,[Time].[Time Calculations].[Current Time] 
  );  
END SCOPE;
```

I was expecting my MTD to be displayed across the dates of the month. but the result is that I just get data at the Month Level.

When I do the same thing over at SSMS w/ the ff.:

```
WITH MEMBER [Time].[Time Calculations].MIKE2 AS
    SUM
    (
      MTD([Time].[Time Hierarchy 1].CURRENTMEMBER)
     ,[Time].[Time Calculations].[Current Time] 
    )
SELECT 
  { 
    ([Time].[Time Calculations].[MTD],[Measures].[Net IMS Volume])
   ,([Time].[Time Calculations].MIKE2,[Measures].[Net IMS Volume])
  } ON 0
  ,[Time].[Time Hierarchy 1].[Date] ON 1
FROM [My Cube];
```

I get data at Date Level. I'm experiencing this on YTD function also.

Comment: `MTD` and `YTD` require specific typing in the cube - has this been set up ok?

Comment: what do you mean specific typing?

Comment: I will add a link and quote to an answer

Comment: did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your time dimensions may not be typed correctly. Specific typing is required for the `YTD` and `MTD` to function as expected.

`MSDN` reference to `YTD` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146039.aspx

In the "remarks" section of the definition:

> If a member expression is not specified, the default is the current
>   member of the first hierarchy with a level of type Years in the first
>   dimension of type Time in the measure group.
>
> The Ytd function is a  shortcut function for the PeriodsToDate function **where the Type
>   property of the attribute hierarchy on which the level is based is set
>   to Years**. That is, Ytd(Member_Expression) is equivalent to
>   PeriodsToDate(Year_Level_Expression,Member_Expression). Note that this
>   function will not work when the Type property is set to FiscalYears.

You could test if this is your problem by converting to the use of PeriodsToDate:

```
WITH MEMBER [Time].[Time Calculations].MIKE2 AS
    SUM
    (
      PeriodsToDate(
           [Time].[Time Hierarchy 1].[Month Level]
         , [Time].[Time Hierarchy 1].CURRENTMEMBER
      )
     ,[Time].[Time Calculations].[Current Time] 
    )
SELECT 
  { 
    ([Time].[Time Calculations].[MTD],[Measures].[Net IMS Volume])
   ,([Time].[Time Calculations].MIKE2,[Measures].[Net IMS Volume])
  } ON 0
  ,[Time].[Time Hierarchy 1].[Date] ON 1
FROM [My Cube];
```